# Set postgres user password on windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, passwords

I would like to set a password for the postgres user on my local database on windows.

Currently I can login to postgres using 
"psql -U postgres"
without the need for a password

My pg_hba file is as follows

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: I've tried alter user postgres with password ... but this didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 4):

First login as usual with `psql -U postgres` and set a password for the user postgres:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'your-new-password';
```

Than edit you file `pg_hba.conf` and add this line:

```
local   all             postgres                                   md5
```

Finally restart the postgres server.

Comment: postgres doesn't seem to restart, do I need to put an address?

Comment: Do you mean, the restart fails? With a error message?

Comment: I'm restarting from the windows task manager - services section, it says stopped in the status when trying to restart

Comment: Probably you made a error by editing the file  `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: I don't think "local   all             postgres                                   md5" works on windows

Comment: Try to restart postgres from the command line, so that so can read the error message. Postgres will tell you, which line cannot be parsed and why.

Comment: Looks like I had a password set over here which was causing problems, C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming/postgresql/pgpass.conf 
All sorted now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. edit pg_hba.conf file: instead 'md5' use 'trust'. *this is for connecting your postgresql server.*
2. reload postgresql
3. pgAdmin4 has an user interface for this. look belove provide your new password here.
4. restore pg_hba.conf file then reload postgresql. DONE it worked for me.

[image][image]

if you do these things by using command prompt. pay attention this

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'your-new-password';
```

it could be like

```
ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD 'your-new-password';
```

because when i look at the postgres from pgAdmin4 it look like a role not user. look at this ss [image]